# Navigation Properties Null until DbSet is called

Tags: entity-framework-core

### Setup

I'm getting into Entity Framework Core (2.1) and I'm having trouble working with the relationships set up. To keep it simple I've set up a simple one-to-one relationship between a person and address table:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public PersonAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class PersonAddress
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

With a simple explicit link between the two (to make sure this isn't an issue in how things are connected):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Address)
        .WithOne(a => a.Person);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonAddress>()
        .HasOne(a => a.Person)
        .WithOne(p => p.Address);
}
```

### Here's my issue

This project is set up in an asp.net core app and I've got a breakpoint set up at the end of my "PeopleController" constructor. I've also added a line to take the first person out of the DbSet and assign it to a variable:

```
public PeopleController(SmallGroupsSiteContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    Person miles = context.Person.First();
    Debug.Print(miles.Address.ToString());
}
```

When I look into my locals and look at the variable "miles" its address field's value is Null. Furthermore if I were to make a call to the DbSet Addresses in my immediate window, the value for Address in the "miles" object gets set to the correct value.

What's going on? When does Entity actually set Navigation Properties? Should I be making calls to other tables as I'd like the data populated? Is there something lazy going on in the background that I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops it looks like I was just a few Google searches away...

It looks like I should have been using the .Include Extension as I was loading the DbSet like so:

```
public PeopleController(SmallGroupsSiteContext context)
{
    _context = context;

    Person miles = context.Person.Include(person => person.Address).First();
    Debug.Print(miles.Address.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Rather than Google searches, you'd better start from [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and from there - [Querying Data - Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). You'll find that eager loading (`Include` / `ThenInclude`) is not the only option :) But no option (even [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) requires enabling) loads the related data by default.